# Why is this C++ question which asks "what is destroying operator delete" an acceptable question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

I just saw [What is "destroying operator delete" in C++20?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67595789/5768908) in the *Hot Network Questions* list.

It's an interesting question, but I'm genuinely confused: how is this question even on-topic? Isn't this kind of question, specially because it was self-answered, a better fit for the defunct "SO Documentation"? It seems to me that it boils down to *"what is this feature?"*.

Comment: *what is this feature?* Isn't that exactly what SO is for, assuming it is in a programming context?

Comment: *specially because it was self-answered* I'm not sure if that is what you meant but let me be 100% sure to get this message across to readers: Self-answering is **not** a sin. It is a blessing.

Comment: How can something be a better fit for something that doesn't exist?

Comment: this a giid question and super answer, most qiestion tend to ask about many aspects or have many questions about the same object, which here is not the case. one problem one solution perfect

Comment: If self-answered questions were categorically off-topic, there wouldn't be a *built-in feature* letting users do that in the same motion as posting the question.

Comment: Thank God someone actually asked a question that's not just another run-of-the-mill "troubleshoot my broken code" or "write my code for me" question.

Comment: The question could show more research. Or is nothing else known about the topic? Did the author google the topic at least? What were the results? (I know it's self answered, still I would expect more info in the question part.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let us remind ourselves what [is on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

The question is about C++. That is a programming language. Those are used in software algorithms and/or programming problems.

It asks about a specific language construct that got introduced recently. That new addition seems to be relevant for solving a practical problem that is unique to software development. Knowing how to apply it usefully in real-life scenarios is relevant knowledge and best captured in a Q&A.

While specifications by themselves are awesome they are often missing practical use cases. That is where a good Q&A can be a valuable addition above the dry and boring specifications.

That a question is a better fit on a (non-existent) location is irrelevant for determining if a question is on-topic here. Nor is the existence of other similar questions that saw a different fate irrelevant to this case.

Comment: What do you mean by *"saw a different faith"*? Do you mean *"saw a different [fate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fate#Noun)"*? Or something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I have fate in you ...

Comment: I still don't see the "practical, answerable problem" aspect of the question. What's the problem being solved? Are we really going to regurgitate people the documentation? The asker needs to explain what the documentation doesn't explain. Remember that there's the  [help/dont-ask]

Comment: @Braiam The problem is that someone has encountered a programming language feature that they don't understand what it does. If we were to disallow such questions, we'll have to purge some 90% of the site.

Comment: @Lundin well, have they read the documentation? What they don't understand about it? OP shows no evidence that they've tried to even parse the documentation.

Comment: @Braiam If we require that the OP has some sort of knowledge in advance before asking questions here, we have to rollback the site to 2014 somewhere. Also in this specific case it's a new language feature and not necessarily even documented properly anywhere.

Comment: @Lundin the asker links to the documentation itself! The documentation first paragraph explains what it does. Are we reading the same question!? "What operator deletes does?" "[It] deallocates storage previously allocated by a matching operator new. "

Comment: @Braiam cppreference.com isn't the documentation, it's just a random web site. It is usually correct but not always. It's similar to Wikipedia as sources go.

Comment: @Braiam I most certainly did not link to the documentation in the question. In addition to cppreference.com not being C++'s official documentation, I'm also not the one who added the links to it.

Comment: @Lundin it's some documentation, not no documentation. Where's OP research? Apparently only found on the answer.

Comment: @Lundin "...cppreference.com isn't the documentation, it's just a random web site. It is usually correct but not always...." Just a side comment but this is basically the same like SO (so don't trust SO either). If there is official documentation on the feature available (and most probably there is), it should be linked to in the question. That's what good research is for.

Answer (score 7):

Generally, self-answered questions are fine but we expect them to hold the same standard as any other question on the site. This can be quite tricky and usually what people mess up when writing such self-answered Q&A.

This specific question is very brief, but it is also asking about a very specific feature. It is perfectly fine and on-topic to ask what a certain programming language feature does or how it works. The question is, in my opinion, sufficiently narrow as well.

The question could perhaps have been improved with some code example where they had encountered the feature. And then the answer could have referred to the very same code in the examples. This would perhaps have turned the post from OK to great, but there's no requirement that every Q&A posted here must be great. Also in terms of up-votes, the post seem to be doing quite well.

Answer (score -7):

> how is this question even on-topic?

Here's the error in your judgement, questions about specific features are on topic. But that doesn't mean that any question about any feature is an acceptable question. It specifically runs afoul of several points raised on the [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) which list questions that while technically on-topic are not acceptable in SO model.

First of all, what is the problem the asker faces? The documentation doesn't explain how the feature should be used? The answer hints that this is not, [in fact it goes to great lengths](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0722r1.html) to do so. And the answer also demonstrates this by basically quoting and regurgitating the documentation linked in the question itself.

If I asked "What is the Referrer-Policy header?" while linking to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy)  documentation,I'm sure many users would ask "did you read the documentation? what didn't you understand about it?". This asker seems to be rewarded for something any other user would get negative feedback for. (Which BTW, is a thing [I totally did](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17648150/792066) the right way.)

Comment: The asker isn't rewarded, their content is.

Comment: @rene no. The asker is rewarded for creating this kind of content. While other askers would have  been heavily penalized for this same  kind of content. So, no, content isn't being rewarded, the asker _is_. As  an example, try to search for a question that was asked in recent times where the asker links to the documentation and asks "what is the thing I'm linking the documentation of does?" (while the documentation is actually as good as cppreference)

Comment: Yes, you're probably right; a low rep user asking the same question might be penalized for it. However, the question is on-topic, and useful, so instead of penalizing this question, we could stop penalizing low rep users asking these kinds of questions?

Comment: @cigien no, we should teach low rep users not to ask those kind of questions by not accepting established users to ask them either.